# Undefined properties of a variable

Tags: javascript, next.js

I don't know if this is too specific to be asked in a Stack Overflow, but I've gone through [a few year old tutorial](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-build-your-own-codepen-app-a8a7140d52d7) on how to build a Codepen-like app with React (NextJS) and MongoDB.

At first I tried to just hand-pick features I actually need for what I am about to do with this app, but then I got stuck in an error message that follows:

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'updatedRecord')

Which refers to my save function (index.js):

```js
const save = async () => {
        setSaving(true);
        const requestOptions = {
            method: !id ? "PUT" : "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                html: htmlValue,
                css: cssValue,
                js: jsValue,
                id: id,
            }),
        };
        const response = await fetch(`../api/pens/${id}`, requestOptions);
        const {
            data: { updatedRecord, newRecordId },
        } = await response.json();

        setSaving(false);
        if (!updatedRecord) {
            await router.push(`?id=${newRecordId}`);
        }
    };
```

This error gets triggered every time I try to save a new pen (by pressing the save button, which calls the save function presented above), and from what I've been able to gather up is that there is probably something that's no longer supported by the newer versions of React/NextJs/MongoDB/NodeJs - just can't figure out what it is.

Here is the version of his (who wrote the tutorial) code in it's entirety. I've pretty much tried everything from cloning the entire project to my own and yet can't get it to work, so I'm in a bit of a pinch here.

Comment: From the looks of it you declare object `data` with property `updatedRecord`, so you need to use `data.updatedRecord` instead.

Comment: @vanowm Sorry if I'm being a complete idiot here, but isn't the `const { data: { updatedRecord, newRecrdId } }` setting those two variables as values to the data-object itself? At least my IDE bombards me with errors, if I try to suggest the `data.updatedRecord` anywhere in the save function, leading to an immediate error on the app.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. So I guess one thing you could do is check what exactly is json fetched: `console.log(await response.json())`

Comment: @vanowm Hm, seems to return `success: false` for some reason. Could it be that the data cuts short at some point during the process? Though everything should be moving from one file to another and function to the next.

Comment: Try replacing the fetch URL with ```/api/pens/${id}```. Also make sure `id` has the correct value.